# Xcode / Swift default files at installation - iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, file

I need to add some "default" file during the installation or the first launch of my app in the "Document" directory to let user access to "demo" files or presets. Is there a way to do it properly ?
It's mostly for iOS Apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very straightforward to get to the app's Documents directory:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Using the above function, you would be able to easily refer to the Documents folder to install files (or a folder containing your demo files) into the Documents directory and then read them out of there.

To copy a default file from your iOS application bundle, you could do something like:

```
let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "defaultfile", withExtension: ".png") // whatever kind of file it is
let destinationFolderURL = self.getDocumentsDirectory()
let fullDestURL = destinationFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("defaultfile.png")
let fileManager = FileManager.default

do{
    try fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Hopefully I didn't make any typos in the above example.  :-)

Comment: thanks this is perfect. So sad iOS doesn't permit to create simply default file at installation.

Answer (score 2):

**Obj-C solution for anyone interested**

If you want user to just read/view those files, all you need to do is to drag&drop them to your project files in Xcode, and then you can access them programmatically like this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"relative/path/to/your/files"]
```

Alternatively, if you want your users to modify/re-save those files, you'll need to copy-paste them from your `NSBundle` to Documents directory on the first launch.

```
- (void)copyDemoFilesToDocumentsFolder {
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *demoFilesPath = [DOCUMENTS_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"path/to/your/demo/files"];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:demoFilesPath]) {
        NSString *sourceFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]
                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"path/to/your/demo/files"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourceFolderPath
                         toPath:demoFilesPath
                          error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to you for effort (and for reminding me that I could have described how to add files to the project in Xcode), but the O.P. was asking for code/techniques in ***swift*** and not objective-c.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann True, I was actually re-writing it in Swift right now. But since you did it — I'll just leave Obj-C solution for anyone who's interested.